# Mysterious blank space appears in text when align evironment followed by figure environment

Tags: spacing, floats, align

When using an `align` environment and subsequently a `figure` environment in Latex code in the resulting pdf appears suddenly a blank space where in code the figure environment resides.

Why does this happen? 
How to fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section{My Chapter}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test.
\begin{align}
 a = b
\end{align}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{Testing a long text string}
 \caption{Test1.}
\end{figure}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\end{figure}%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the end of line after `\end{figure}` doesn't produce a visible space. Actually, the code will carry on a possible white space coming from *before* the environment, adding a normal space if `figure` starts in paragraph mode and there was no space before `\begin{figure}`.

So

```
Before\begin{figure}
<code>
\end{figure}
Test
```

will produce a regular

> Before Test

as well as

```
Before
\begin{figure}
<code>
\end{figure}
Test
```

However, we are at the end of a math display and this has the consequence that we end up in a case similar to `Before\begin{figure}`, which adds a space.

The `align` environment is not relevant to the issue: the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}    

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
text
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{Testing a long text string}
 \caption{Test1.}
\end{figure}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test.
\end{document}
```

shows the same behavior.

In general my advice is to always type `figure` and `table` environments surrounded by blank lines, so the problem cannot appear in the first place.

In your case I'm afraid the only other way around is to type

```
\end{figure}%
```

Comment: When I surround these environments by blank lines, I will always have a new paragraph starting, don't I? Then, again, I would have an (even larger) indentation...

Comment: @user3185454 we are dealing with floating environments here, so a minor change in their position in the source has minimal effect (as long as the paragraphs are not excessively long). This is a personal choice, but I typically insert the figure code after the paragraph where I first introduce/discuss the figure.